# How to enter java variables into an external website with webview using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, string, webview

I have an app which searches the result of an OCR app, however I can't find a way to enter these results into my webview. I have tried it this way, but it doesn't enter anything into the search bar.

```
String drug1 = "tetracycline";

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String weburl){
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('livesearch-interaction-basic').value = <%= drug1 %>; null");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].click()");
```

However, the rest of the code is working fine as this works perfectly.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String weburl){
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('livesearch-interaction-basic').value = 'isotretinoin'; null");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].click()");
```

I have also tried

```
.value = String(<%= drug1 %>); null");
.value = (<%= drug1 %>); null");
.value = drug1; null");
.value = <%= drug1 %>; null");
.value = (drug1); null");
etc.
```

There are no errors, it simply only searches the second one. Am I missing something?

Is it possible to use the string in my JS code like this and if not, how would I go about searching the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can process the url in a string variable before loading it in webview.

```java
String drug1 = "tetracycline";
String finalUrl = "javascript:document.getElementById('livesearch-interaction-basic').value = '"+ drug1 + "'; null";
webView.loadUrl(finalUrl);
```